# If you say you couldn't does it mean you can now?

Tags: past-tense, could

If you use couldn't does it mean you can/ do now?

E.g.
1. I tried to fix the machine but I couldn't figure out the problem. (Does it mean I do now?)
2. I was admitted to hospital but they couldn't work out what the problem was.

Is it also possible to say?
1. I tried to fix the machine but I can't figure out the problem.
2. I was admitted to hospital but they can't work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first examples do not logically preclude the possibility that you can now, but neither do they imply it. At the time you were fixing the machine, you could not figure out what the problem was. Most people would infer that nothing else has happened since which might change your ability to fix the problem. Similarly, the inference would be that if you returned to the same hospital for the same investigations, they would still not be able to work out the problem.

In your second situation, the tenses create a different situation. "I was admitted to hospital but they can't work out what the problem is." suggests that you are still at the hospital and they haven't given up on you yet. (It reads a little like a Facebook update, for example.) With the machine, it's harder to reconcile the mixed tenses. Perhaps "I am trying to fix the machine but I can't figure out the problem."

Another useful phrasing is "I have yet to figure out the problem" = I am still trying to and haven't given up.

Comment: Doing direct translation can be tricky sometimes.

here's an example:

I was discharged 2 days ago. My flatmate asked me what happened or what were the findings. I answered her. "They were able to manage my pain, but they couldn't figure out what the problem was" I said that because it would come out naturally. However, if I were to directly translate it into my own language the context would change. It would mean they figured out later on. but the thing is they still haven't up to this time.

Comment: @RafaelM: if you want to imply that it is possible now, use "then": "They couldn't figure it out _then_." Although it doesn't explicitly state that they can figure it out now (it could also be in the future), it's commonly understood to mean the present.